# Oracle VM VirtualBox;Shared folder does not exist on the host?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, shared-folders

I had installed `Oracle VM VirtualBox version 4.2.10 r84104` on Windows 7.Then I create a Windows seven operating system(form an iso image file) as a guest on it with a `shred folder`.But when I try to start guest,I see this warning:

[image]

So I reinstalled `VirtualBox`,but problem remains yet.How I can solve this problem?May be it correspond to this version of VirtualBox?

Comment: Did you create the folder first and then add it in VBox?

Comment: @BJ292 Yes.I first create folder and then add it.

Comment: I don't see why it would make a difference but you might want to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I juts had the same error and this is how I resolved it:
Host OS is Windows 7 64bit, Virtual Box 4.3.12, Guest OS is Oracle Linux 6.4
(at the time of writing this post Virtual Box 4.3.14 has a bug which makes it unusable, so until further notice it is best to use Virtual Box 4.3.12)

1. shut down Virtual Box.
2. download separately VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.12.iso from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/
3. rename it to VBoxGuestAdditions.iso and copy over C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
4. Start Virtual Box, start guest OS.
5. Insert VBoxGuestAdditions.iso disk and run it.
6. It will (on Linux) compile for a while and afterwards it will allow shared folder (check it as root with df-k, the name shoud be like: shared 604544340 197580404 406963936 33% **/media/sf_shared**